# Hide link using css bracket attribute, no access to HTML

Tags: html, css

I don't have access to the HTML but need to hide this link (#wall)

```
<td class="status_value"><span class="online">              - 
    <a href="#wall">
      Leave a Comment
    </a>

    <a href="#today">
      Join today
    </a>
```

I have tried using

```
td.status_value[href='#wall']{display:none;}
```

Comment: How about `td.status_value [href="#wall"]`

Comment: You really should accept your answers to help future users. None of the questions you've asked have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

Target the `<a>` inside the table cell, instead of the table cell itself:

So

```
td.status_value[href='#wall']{display:none;}
```

Becomes

```
td.status_value a[href='#wall']{display:none;}
```

Comment: perfect thanks, tried everything but including the "a" .... i hate learning this stuff !  Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to target your anchor:

```
td.status_value a[href='#wall']{display:none;}
```